# google custom search engine - search only under specific link

Tags: google-custom-search, google-search-api

i am using the google custom search engine via json api.
the request look like this:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=*****&cx=*****
 &start=1&num=10&q=form"
```

now, i wont to search for example the word "form" only in one page in my site.

for example, i have three page in my site:

www.site.com/services

www.site.com/payments

www.site.com/forms

and i wont that the search will be only in the page "forms"

it's possible to filter the search for only one page?

i try to locking for some parameter in this link

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list#request

but nothing not lock like what i need.

any idea? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a URL pattern and refinement labels from the Custom Search control panel.
See: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4542637